# Do I need to use HTML tags for en as well as em dashes?

Tags: html, xhtml, kindle

I'm editing the HTML for an ebook. I'm using — (`&mdash;`) for when there is an em dash, but do I need to do the same for a regular hyphen, as in "micro-dot" or "over-sensitive"? Or can I just leave the "-" as-is in the text?

Comment: An endash is not the same as a hyphen. The hyphen is not even a dash per se. And as long as you're writing hyphens, there's no need to HTML encode them. There *is* an explicit hyphen in Unicode, but every book I've seen uses the "hyphen/minus" you suggest. Also, this site may not be the best fit for this question. :)

Comment: As you asking about what HTML wants, or about what a human reader wants?

Comment: If you are using UTF-8 (which is recommended anyway, so why not) you won't have to use references at all (except for the obvious `<` `&` `>`). That said, why? What gave you the idea that ordinary hyphen-minus signs would be better off as references? By the way, references are not tags.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use the entity `&mdash;`, since you can enter “—” as such, if the e-book is UTF-8 encoded, as it should. Neither do you need to change `&mdash;` to the em dash itself, if you now have it in the data.

There is no need to escape the common hyphen, i.e. the Ascii hyphen (officially called HYPHEN-MINUS in Unicode), in any way in HTML.

Note that at least according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/), the words “microdot” and “oversensitive” are written without a hyphen. If you would like the spell them that way but specify an allowed hyphenation point (for automatic hyphenation by a browser), you would use the SOFT HYPHEN character (U+00AD). It, too, can be written as such in HTML, but since it is normally invisible, you might find it more convenient to use a named character reference `&shy;` for it, e.g.

```
micro&shy;dot
```